# boto VPC get_all_dhcp_options() filter by domain-name

Tags: boto, amazon-vpc

Should be a pretty simple thing, but I couldn't find a clue anywhere. I want to run get_all_dhcp_options() but set filters so that only those that match a certain domain-name are returned.

Answer (score 3):

> If anyone has better way, please let me know.

I understand to get the answer directly as @garnaat did is simple, but on **how to get the filter key** is not that direct.

What I did here is the instruction to find out the key/value easily.  This is a general way for finding any keys in boto, not only vpc, same for ec2, s3, etc.

```
$ python

>>> import boto.vpc
>>> c = boto.vpc.connect_to_region('us-west-2')  # or whatever
>>> c.get_all_dhcp_options()
[DhcpOptions:dopt-12dc23d1, DhcpOptions:dopt-426e82c7]
>>> for dhcp in c.get_all_dhcp_options():
...   print dir(dhcp)
...
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'add_tag', 'add_tags', 'connection', 'endElement', 'id', 'item', 'options', 'region', 'remove_tag', 'remove_tags', 'startElement', 'tags']
```

It makes sense that the domain name should be in `options`, but you can verify it by login aws management console, click `VPC` => `DHCP Options Sets`, the domain name is in column `options`. So continue the debug:

```
>>> for dhcp in c.get_all_dhcp_options():
...   print dhcp.options
...
{u'domain-name': [u'us-west-2.compute.internal'], u'domain-name-servers': [u'AmazonProvidedDNS']}
{u'domain-name': [u'abc.example.com xyz.example.com'], u'domain-name-servers': [u'10.0.0.1', u' 10.0.0.2'], u'ntp-servers': [u'10.0.0.1', u' 10.0.0.2']}
...
```

So now you get the key which is `domain-name`, and you also know the other keys `domain-name-servers`, `ntp-servers`. Then you should confidently put the filter now.

```
>>> c.get_all_dhcp_options(filters={'key': 'domain-name', 'value': 'us-west-2.compute.internal'})
[DhcpOptions:dopt-426e82c7]
```

After you get the result properly, you can add above steps in your codes.

Good luck.

Comment: There is a general problem of knowing which filters are supported by a particular API call.  Boto does not help you with that.  In the past, I have resorted to looking at the EC2 API docs.  Now, I generally use the ``help`` command in AWSCLI to find out.

Comment: Thanks @garnaat. That's a work around. But in boto, seems there is no easy way to list the keys. By the way, is it possible to update your answer and give the detail steps on how to get the key with `AWSCLI`?

Comment: Right, there is no way to get this in boto.  That's because there is no API provided that returns this information.  I have edited the answer below to give more info about getting the filter docs via AWSCLI.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
import boto.vpc
c = boto.vpc.connect_to_region('us-west-2')  # or whatever
c.get_all_dhcp_options(filters={'key': 'domain-name', 'value': 'us-west-2.compute.internal'})
```

Obviously, use whatever domain name makes sense in your situation.

Finding out which filter key/values are supported by a given API call is another problem.  Unfortunately, boto does not provide a way to do this mainly because there is no API that provides this information.  However, if you have the AWSCLI, it has help information that comes directly from the service documentation so it does list the available filters.

To find what filters are supported you have to know that the `get_all_*` method calls in boto map to the `Describe*` API calls in EC2 and those, in turn, are available in the AWSCLI as `describe-*` commands.  So:

```
aws ec2 describe-dhcp-options help
```

will display all of the help for the API call including the supported filters.  Its a roundabout way  of getting the info but its better than looking it up in the API docs.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the updates. In fact, after run aws with help command,  I can't get full list of keys (for example, there is no key of `ntp-servers` in help).  I think directly run command `aws ec2 describe-dhcp-options` is better way. From the output, I can clearly understand the key/value structure.